MudTheme Palette darker version of costum colors when hovering over a e.g. button?
    public static MudTheme CustomTheme = new MudTheme()
        {
            Palette = new Palette()
            {
                Primary = "#001478",
                Secondary = "#00B0F0",
                Error = "#F44336",
                Success = "#4CAF50",
                Warning = " #FF1493",
                Info = "#2196F3",
                BackgroundGrey = "BEBEBE",
                GrayDarker = "#00000099"
            },
            LayoutProperties = new LayoutProperties()
            {
                DrawerWidthLeft = "260px",
                DrawerWidthRight = "300px"
            }
        };

private void SetThemeColor(string colorConfName, string colorValue)
{
    switch (colorConfName)
    {
        case "mudtheme.palette.primary":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Primary = colorValue;
            break;
        case "mudtheme.palette.secondary":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Secondary = colorValue;
            break;
        case "mudtheme.palette.error":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Error = colorValue;
            break;
        case "mudtheme.palette.success":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Success = colorValue;
            break;
        case "mudtheme.palette.warning":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Warning = colorValue;
            break;
        case "mudtheme.palette.info":
            CustomTheme.Palette.Info = colorValue;
            break;
    }
}

When setting these custom colors for my MudTheme Palette it changes the colors correctly.
When i hover over a button it still shows the darker version of the standard color. Do i need to set all these color variants manually or is there a way MudBlazor derives the lighter/darker version of a set color automatically that it uses to show UI interaction?

It's not automatic, you have to manually set the colours for palette for each colour

Ok thank you. Is there then a possibility to use the colors from my custom palette via Style or Class ind a component like here:


In the MudBlazor documentation it is done like this:
.mud-theme-primary
This works but only for the default colors i think.

Yes you can, I recccomend using CSS classes. In most cases though you will have to add an important! to each CSS property.
